# Cómo puedo obtener el primer y ultimo día de una semana concreta en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría saber como puedo obtener el primer y último día de una semana en concreto en Javascript.

Por ejemplo, si tengo la semana 14 del año 2016, obtener que el primer día es el 4 de Abril (Lunes) y el último el 10 de Abril (Domingo).

Lo único que he encontrado ha sido tomando como *Date* la fecha actual del sistema, pero no de una semana en concreto.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Voy a dejar dos métodos para hacer cálculos sin necesidad de bibliotecas externas, sólo con JavaScript. Cada método devolverá valores diferentes.

**Método 1: semana natural**

Este método considera que la primera semana del año empieza el primer día del año, sin importar qué día es en concreto.

- Crea una función a la que le pases el año Y y la semana X
- En esa función, crea una fecha con el primer día del año Y (1 de enero de Y)
- Añádele 7 * (número de semanas - 1) días a la fecha
- La fecha obtenida será el primer día de la semana X del año Y
- Añádele 6 días y tendrás el último día de la semana X del año Y

Aquí dejo una demo (simplifico un poco el cálculo del primer y último día de la semana):

```js
var meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
var dias = ["Domingo","Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];

function calculaSemana() {
  
  // obtenemos los valores de año y semana (asumimos que son valores válidos)
  var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
  var week = document.getElementById("week").value;
  
  // añadimos validación a la semana
  if (week < 1 || week > 53) { alert("Error: la semana debe ser un número entre 1 y 53"); return false; }
  
  // obtenemos el primer y último día de la semana del año indicado
  var primer = new Date(year, 0, (week - 1) * 7 + 1);
  var ultimo = new Date(year, 0, (week - 1) * 7 + 7);
  
  // mostramos el resultado
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = 
    "El primer día de la " + week + "<sup>a</sup> semana de " + year + " es " + primer.getDate() + " de " + meses[primer.getMonth()] + " (" + dias[primer.getDay()] + ")<br/>" +
    "El último día de la " + week + "<sup>a</sup> semana de " + year + " es " + ultimo.getDate() + " de " + meses[ultimo.getMonth()] + " (" + dias[ultimo.getDay()] + ")"; 
  
}
```

```html
<input type="year" id="year" placeholder="Año" />
<input type="number" id="week" placeholder="Semana" min="1" max="53" />
<input type="button" onclick="calculaSemana()" value="Calcular" />

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

**Método 2: semana ISO**

Este método considera que la primera semana del año empieza el primer lunes del año (lo cuál puede dejar algunos días huérfanos de semana).

La idea es similar al método anterior, la única diferencia es que primero calculamos qué día de la semana es el primer día del año, y a partir de ahí ajustamos para que la fecha calculada siempre coincida con lunes.

Aquí dejo una demo:

```js
var meses = ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
var dias = ["Domingo","Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"];

function calculaSemana() {

  // obtenemos los valores de año y semana (asumimos que son valores válidos)
  var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
  var week = document.getElementById("week").value;

  // obtenemos el primer dia del año
  var primerdia = new Date(year, 0, 1);
  
  // obtenemos la corrección necesaria
  var correccion = 6 - primerdia.getDay();
  
  // validación para la semana
  if (week * 7 + correccion > 365) { alert("El valor para semana no es válido"); return false; }
  
  // obtenemos el lunes y domingo de la semana especificada
  var primer = new Date(year, 0, (week - 1) * 7 + 3 + correccion);
  var ultimo = new Date(year, 0, (week - 1) * 7 + 9 + correccion);

  // mostramos el resultado
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = 
    "El primer día de la " + week + "<sup>a</sup> semana de " + year + " es " + primer.getDate() + " de " + meses[primer.getMonth()] + " (" + dias[primer.getDay()] + ")<br/>" +
    "El último día de la " + week + "<sup>a</sup> semana de " + year + " es " + ultimo.getDate() + " de " + meses[ultimo.getMonth()] + " (" + dias[ultimo.getDay()] + ")"; 

}
```

```html
<input type="year" id="year" placeholder="Año" />
<input type="number" id="week" placeholder="Semana" min="1" max="53" />
<input type="button" onclick="calculaSemana()" value="Calcular" />

<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Como dije, hacerlo manualmente introduce bugs, si te fijas de poner la primera semana de 2016, resulta en que empieza un sábado y termina un viernes. Lo cual es incorrecto.

Comment: @rnd No es un bug, es una feature :P

Comment: En mi defensa diré que OP no especificó si quería la semana natural (el primer día del año sería el comienzo de la primera semana) o la primera semana completa (empezando en lunes). Ahora corrijo para que sea la primera semana completa.

Comment: Ok.. jaja.. Bueno, pero dijo que era una semana ISO. lo cual esta bien especificado.

Comment: De nuevo en mi defensa: ha debido editar lo de la semana ISO, porque es la primera vez que lo veo en la pregunta.

Comment: jajajaj.. espera no lo dice.. ahora recuerdo, lo deduje por las fechas que puso como ejemplo.

Comment: Voto +1, por el valor de hacerlo a mano sobre usar una libreria titanica como momentjs

Comment: Alvaro, ahora falla cuando pones semana 52 de 2015, dice que termina el 3 de enero de 2015 cuando termina el 3 de Enero de 2016.

Comment: Ok, ok. 52 no es un valor válido para 2015. Voy a añadir validación de semana para corregir eso

Comment: no estoy criticando la respuesta, solo reafirmando el punto al que me refería cuando decía que las fechas son complejas. No quise molestar.

Comment: @rnd No molestas para nada. Llevas razón en que se debería validar los errores. Voy a editar la solución para eso

Comment: esta es una formula que funciona pues se que esta implementada en un sistema de mi empresa. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Calculating_the_week_number_of_a_given_date

Comment: @jasilva Hacerlo a mano, es como lo hacen los valientes. Muy bien.

Comment: ...O los locos :P. Como bien indica @rnd en su respuesta, hay bastantes limitaciones que se podrían evitar usando librerías y plugins.

Answer (score 6):

Date tiene sus limitaciones, siempre puedes crear tus propios métodos pero las fechas son complicadas pues hay varias excepciones a la regla. Por esto, usar una librería como [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) incluye soluciones y no problemas.

Te dejo un ejemplo, (debes abrir la consola con F12 para ver los resultados)

```js
console.log(moment().isoWeek(14).startOf("isoweek"));
console.log(moment().isoWeek(14).endOf("isoweek"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.js"></script>
```

```
Moment {Mon Apr 04 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time)}
Moment {Sun Apr 10 2016 23:59:59 GMT-0300 (Argentina Standard Time)}
```

Answer (score 2):

**

> Otra forma de sacar la semana, de lunes - domingo, dándole una fecha
>   de entrada

**

```
var myDate = new Date('2017/09/08');
myDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

myDate.setYear(2017);
```

// Seteamos la fecha con un valor mayor a 0

```
myDate.setDate(1);
```

// Indicamos el número de mes y le restamos 1

```
myDate.setMonth(09 - 1);
```

// Nos posicionamos en el día Lunes

```
var monday = 1;

while(myDate.getDay() != monday) {
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

// primer día de la semana

```
console.log(myDate);
```

// último día de la semana

```
console.log(new Date(myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 6)));
```

Answer (score 1):

En oracle se puede obtener de la siguiente manera

```
select to_char(to_date(sysdate),'IW') SEMANA,
       UPPER(to_char(sysdate,'day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = SPANISH')) DIA,
       TO_CHAR(DECODE(LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(to_char(sysdate,'day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = SPANISH')))),
             'LUNES',SYSDATE,
             'MARTES',SYSDATE-1,
             'MIERCOLES',SYSDATE-2,
             'JUEVES',SYSDATE-3,
             'VIERNES',SYSDATE-4,
             'SABADO',SYSDATE-5,
             'DOMINGO',SYSDATE-6),'DD/MM/YYYY') FECHA_INICIAL,
       TO_CHAR(DECODE(LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(to_char(sysdate,'day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = SPANISH')))),
             'LUNES',SYSDATE+6,
             'MARTES',SYSDATE+5,
             'MIERCOLES',SYSDATE+4,
             'JUEVES',SYSDATE+3,
             'VIERNES',SYSDATE+2,
             'SABADO',SYSDATE+1,
             'DOMINGO',SYSDATE),'DD/MM/YYYY') FECHA_FINAL
              from dual;
```

Comment: Buen día Geovanni, espero te encuentres bien, gracias por la respuesta en Oracle, sin embargo esta pregunta está orientada a JavaScript. Te invito a revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que tengas una mayor claridad con el funcionamiento del sitio. Saludos :D

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera se puede encontrar el primer y ultimo dia de la semana partiendo del numero de semana y el año que se necesite consultar, en este caso el 32 es el codigo de la semana para el año 2017

```
select TO_date(DECODE(LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(to_char((to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7)),'day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = SPANISH')))),
             'LUNES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7)),
             'MARTES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))-1,
             'MIERCOLES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))-2,
             'JUEVES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))-3,
             'VIERNES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))-4,
             'SABADO',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))-5,
             'DOMINGO',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))-6),'DD/MM/YYYY'),
       TO_date(DECODE(LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(to_char((to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7)),'day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = SPANISH')))),
             'LUNES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))+6,
             'MARTES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))+5,
             'MIERCOLES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))+4,
             'JUEVES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))+3,
             'VIERNES',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))+2,
             'SABADO',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))+1,
             'DOMINGO',(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7))),'DD/MM/YYYY')
   from dual
     where to_number(to_char(to_date('01/01/2017')+(32*7),'IW')) = 32;
```

Comment: Geovanni, bienvenido a SOes, gracias por tu animo por participar. Lamento decirte esto, pero has proporcionado una muy mala respuesta. La pregunta indica especificamente que debe ser en Javascript. ¿Hay alguna razon por lo que has puesto (aparentemente) una consulta para Transact-Sql? A parte de eso, te invito a leer en el [help]  para ver las herramientas que tenemos para adjuntar código y despues de eso a [edit] tu respuesta para sea acorde a la pregunta. De otra forma, es posible que sea borrada. Y por cierto, hazte el [tour] para aprender mas de este sitio y la manera de publicar. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Espero este código ayude a varias personas (recicle algún código que encontré en aquí).
De esta manera sacamos las semanas naturales de un año en especifico, la semana 1 empieza el primero de enero del año que se eligió y finaliza el domingo más cercano.

```js
function calculaSemana() {
  
  // obtenemos los valores de año y semana (asumimos que son valores válidos)
  var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
  var week = document.getElementById("week").value;


// Simplemente para formatear la salida
  function formatDate(date) {
   return date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear()
  }
  //Aquí obtenemos el primer domingo del año
  var sunday = new Date(year, 0, 1);

  while (sunday.getDay() != 0) {
   sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() + 1);
  }

  //Si la semana es 1 empieza en el dia 1 de enero y termina el domingo más cercano
  if (week ==1)
  {
   var primer = new Date(year, 0, (week - 1) * 7 + 1);
   var ultimo = new Date(year, 0, (week - 1) * 7 + sunday.getDate());
  }
  else
  {
   // obtenemos el primer y último día de la semana del año indicado
   var primer = new Date(year, 0, (week - 1) * 7 - (7 - sunday.getDate()) + 1);
   var ultimo = new Date(year, 0, (week - 1) * 7 + sunday.getDate());
  }
  alert('Semana del ' + formatDate(primer) + " al " + formatDate(ultimo));
    
    }
```

```html
<input type="year" id="year" placeholder="Año" />
<input type="number" id="week" placeholder="Semana" min="1" max="53" />
<input type="button" onclick="calculaSemana()" value="Calcular" />

<div id="resultado"></div>
```