# Sacar dias de la semana por año

Tags: javascript, date

vi una respuesta que se hizo hace un tiempo y me gustaría saber si alguien sabe como mejorar el proceso de sacar los dias de la semana   arreglando los errores de fechas en semana 52.

[Cómo puedo obtener el primer y ultimo día de una semana concreta en Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7003/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-obtener-el-primer-y-ultimo-d%C3%ADa-de-una-semana-concreta-en-javascript/7011#7011)

Comment: Creo que esa respuesta es mía... Dime qué errores da para la semana 52 y le echo un ojo para mejorarla.

Comment: Hola Alvaro, el problema que me da es al poner la 1era semana del año, en algunos casos se salta a la segunda, y  otros al poner la semana 52 no hace validación de fecha para ir por ejemplo del 2016 al 2017, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da un vistazo a esa libreria [Moments.js](http://momentjs.com/) sirve para manejar fechas y tiempo.

Entiendo que para tu propósito seria usar [day of week](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/)

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/

Answer (score 1):

> Otra forma de sacar la semana, de lunes - domingo, dándole una fecha
>   de entrada

```
var myDate = new Date('2017/09/08');
myDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

myDate.setYear(2017);
```

// Seteamos la fecha con un valor mayor a 0

```
myDate.setDate(1);
```

// Indicamos el número de mes y le restamos 1

```
myDate.setMonth(09 - 1);
```

// Nos posicionamos en el día Lunes

```
var monday = 1;

while(myDate.getDay() != monday) {
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
}
```

// primer día de la semana

```
console.log(myDate);
```

// último día de la semana

```
console.log(new Date(myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 6)));
```